# jQuery animate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, colors, jquery-animate

My function looks like that

```
$.fn.animateHighlight = function(highlightColor, originalColor, type, duration) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = 500;
    var animateVal1 = {};
    animateVal1[type] = highlightColor;
    var animateVal2 = {}; 
    animateVal2[type] = originalColor;
    this.stop().animate(animateVal1, animateMs).delay(duration).animate(animateVal2, animateMs);
};
```

Calling this like that

```
 $("#variants").animateHighlight("red", "#9c9c9c", "borderColor", 3000);
```

The problem is,

This is default border color of fieldset

[image]

And this is after animation color

[image]

I know that animate adds extra style attribute to element. What I wanna do is, return back original fieldset border color (removing style attribute will return back original border color).

Tried to change last line of function to this

```
this.stop().animate(animateVal1, animateMs).delay(duration).animate(animateVal2, animateMs).removeAttribute('style');
```

Animate didn't even start.

How can I animate and reset back to original version after flashing?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.stop().animate(animateVal1, animateMs).delay(duration).animate(animateVal2, animateMs, function() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

Comment: Can İ directly animate and reset? I mean not to use second color but directly to original state?

Comment: Have no idea, try to just animate the border color to transparent and see if it works, you may have to use rgba colors for this though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two method for this.

1.If you used border color in stye attribute for VariantDiv.Default Styles will be lost in style when you remove style attribute. So you should hold first border color.

For Example :

http://jsfiddle.net/tEwa9/

2.if when you don't use style you can do this way.
You can call this code when animate completed.

```
$(this).attr('style','');
```

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSYWS/